# Is it possible to receive a msg on a certain topic by calling a service?

Tags: service, msg, synchronization, topics, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working with gazebo, where I created an indoor environment and a mobile robot. The robot is equipped with an RGB-D camera and a logical_camera. Now, I would like to write a node that, given an array of poses, does the following:

- publishes a msg on /gazebo/set_model_state to position the robot at the current desired pose
- acquires sensors measurements (i.e. rgb, depth and logical_camera images)
- does the required processing
- does the same for the next poses

So far, I wrote a subscriber using a  message filter (with approximate time sync policy) to read the required messages but I'm not so sure on how to go on. By considering the operations highlighted in the bullets, I think that in pseudocode the node should be something like:

```
while(nh.ok() && it!=pose_array.end()){ 
  gazebo_msgs::ModelState next_pose;
  pose_pub.publish(next_pose);
 
  /* 
    read sensor measurements
  */

  /* 
    processing
  */

  ++it 
  ros::spinOnce();
  loop_rate.sleep();
}
```

So my question is the following: is it possible to call a service (or something similar) to receive the sensor messages on demand (instead of using callbacks) in the while loop?

Of course, I'd be very glad even if someone can point me out a better solution to this problem!!!

Thanks.

---

EDIT: @jayess This is because I need to acquire a dataset to train a classifier, so I just need a set of images in certain positions of the environment. I could do this by teleoperating the robot and triggering the storage of the images with the joystick. But since I need to acquire a lot of image, I was thinking of an automated way to do this! So, if I subscribe to a topic, the callback that does the processing will be called for each sensor measurement. Instead I need to read the sensors output only when the robot is in the desired position.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275865/is-it-possible-to-receive-a-msg-on-a-certain-topic-by-calling-a-service?/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2017-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-14**:
You *could* use a service to get the sensor messages but the driver/node publishing that information would have to have a service server implemented. Can you explain *why* you want to do it this way vs. subscribing to a topic with callbacks?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-14**:
I'm not sure I fully understand what you're looking for, but you could create some kind of intermediary node that subscribes to the image topic and implements a service server that will just serve what ever image it has when requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not exactly a service, but I believe you're really just asking for a way to receive a single message at a certain time of your choosing.

See #q270298, #q264490 and #q231320 for similar questions (and answers).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2017-11-14**:
Thanks! It's exactly what I was looking for! I just have one last question: using ros::topic::waitformessage() is it possible to receive msgs from different topics with approximately equal timestamps (i.e. like message_filters)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
No, not in the default implementation.

You could perhaps create something that does similar things, using `waitForMessage(..)` as inspiration.